# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

Okay so I am using AVFoundation to scan barcodes. Then once scanned go to another view. Works well. However, at random times the app will crash out. With the camera preview still showing, just won't work. I get the error:

> **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)**

I believe this maybe due it trying to access something without it being loaded yet. Correct me if I am wrong.

So, what I'm asking is how do I solve this ?

If any aid I have attached the thread also.

[image: image of thread]

Comment: Did you already add an all exceptions breakpoint? If not then do so and see where the error is thrown.
Most probably you will find some optional being nil while accessing its contents unchecked with an exclamation mark.

Comment: @HermannKlecker sorry I am pretty new to iOS development. By all exceptions breakpoint do you mean (!) ? If so where abouts would I add it

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post your code.

Comment: In the break points navigator add one by klicking on the + sign and choose  an exception breakpoint. That will make your app to stop in the debugger just before the exception is thrown. Doing so you can easily localize the root cause in about 98% of all exceptions.

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi http://pastebin.com/xeYNQD9W

Comment: @HermannKlecker Thank you shall try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, Optionals are a special generic type that:

- can contain a value
- or no value at all (nil)

A variable can only be nil when it’s an optional. You declare an optional like this:

```
let meaningOfLife:Int? = 42
```

The question mark ? at the end of the type declaration denotes that the variable meaningOfLife is an optional. Therefore, this code is OK:

```
meaningOfLife = nil
```

The variable meaningOfLife is an optional, so it can be nil.

This example, however, is invalid:

```
let age:Int = 99
age = nil // This line is not OK
```

Because age isn’t an optional, it can’t be nil!

Optionals are a powerful feature of Swift, because they make your code safer and less error-prone. As a result, optionals make you more productive as a developer, because you spend less time on fixing bugs.

Almost every programming language has something similar to nil. It’s undefined in JavaScript, null in Java and NULL in PHP. In these languages, to avoid runtime errors with variables that have no value, you have to remember to check if a variable is null. That’s something you could forget…

Swift handles optionals in a special way: it forces the developer to check whether a variable is nil, if it’s an optional. This is called unwrapping. You need to unwrap an optional before you can use it.

When you forgot to unwrap an optional, you’ll find out before your app runs, which saves you time. This makes you more productive, and your code less buggy.

Unlike other languages, Swift will check whether optionals are properly unwrapped at compile-time. So before the app runs, when the code is compiled, Swift will check every optional in your code and see if you’ve properly unwrapped it.

Unfortunately, some errors can’t be caught by the compiler. That’s when you’ll see this error.

This happens while your app is running, in the following scenarios:

- You’ve force-unwrapped an optional with !
- An implicitly unwrapped optional is nil

Before you force-unwrap optional, you check with an if-statement whether the optional is nil. When optional is nil, the code inside the squiggly brackets { } isn’t executed.